# Scroll using setContentOffSet button

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to figure out Scroll Views and how to make them scroll programatically.

I have set up 2 screens (image views) in one view controller.
[image] 
[image]

I add contraints to the image views and the scroll view by selecting the top bottom left and right, and the height and width.

My view controller has this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

@IBAction func toFloorplan(_ sender: Any) {
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:1366, y:0), animated: false)
}}
```

and a simple button that calls toFloorPlan.

I can scroll left and right using paging, but when I click the button, my app quits and I get the following print out. Thanks for your help!!

> 2017-03-30 18:20:13.423801 VHThenNow[78847:14546188] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>       Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
>       Try this: 
>           (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
>           (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
>   (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       ""
>   )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
>   The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
>   fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

Comment: You got conflicting constraints, that's what the print out is saying. The generate approach is the scrollview should only have 1 subview. In that subview, you can add as many subviews as you want. For your case, I recommend the left image view, pin the `top, left and bottom` to contentView. For the right image view, pin the `top, right, bottom` to contentView. Make right image view's leading match left image view's trailing. Conflicting constraints don't crash the app. Sounds like the problem is something else if you app crashes. What happens if your comment out `toFloorPlan` inner statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
```

And create outlet - connect scrollview in storyboard with scrollview variable.
Your constraint wrong but it does not reason of crash